# Socket Creation Exception

Tags: java, sockets

I have a little technical problem. I want to read data using Java Socket at localhost. The data will be continuously sent by an external simulator. Just for testing I have written small code but there is exception. I am not sure why this exception is generated as every thing looks fine.

```
public class ReceiveFromSocket {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 3333);
    DataInputStream in;
    while (true) {
        try {
            socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
            in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            System.out.println(in.readUTF());
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
  }

}
```

And when I run it I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
at data.ReceiveFromSocket.main(ReceiveFromSocket.java:27)
Java Result: 1
```

Can any one point what I am missing.

Comment: Well, you specify a client socket only in your code; where is the server side?

Comment: I don't have server. I have to collect data from a simulator program where I can set port and IP address for sending data. So in simulator I have set IP address 127.0.0.1 and port 3333. Which will send all the data to localhost on port 3333. So I was trying to collect that data and use it for my purpose.

Comment: Nothing is listening at localhost:3333, obviously. And surely the simulator is a client, not a server? And is the external simulator really going to send you data in readUTF() format?

Comment: Well the simulator is sending data using UDP protocol.

Answer (score 0):

> Well the simulator is send data using UDP protocol

Well your code is using the TCP protocol. Have a look at `DatagramSocket` instead of `Socket`. And forget about `readUTF()` as per my comment.

Comment: I used DatagramSocket and don't know ho to convert it to useful out put. Because DatagramSocket can receive DatagramPacket and from DatagramPacket we can only gets Byte[] data. When I converted it to string it shows some random symbols.

Comment: When you convert it to String how? The correct way is `new String(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), packet.getLength())`.